# What symbol(s) best represent the action of "connecting"?

Tags: icons, symbols

What symbol(s) best represent the action of "connecting"? I need an icon that represents a "connection" - specifically, a connection between people.

Let's say there is a button to "connect" with another user on some website, what symbol would graphically represent the action of connecting?

Comment: A plug is a logical symbol (with unfortunate potential innuendo)

Comment: plug is more often used for plug-ins, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, connected instances are represented with a link (as in *links connected in a chain*):

[image: example linked layers in Photoshop]

But if it is going to represent a **connection between persons**, maybe two holding hands: [image: icon holding hands]

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this done with two little people icons and a double sided arrow between them, indicating a two-way connection. I can't find an example, otherwise I'd post it here!

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from you are the parameters 1. website 2. connecting two users. This latter action has to made visible. No idea who your target group is, here are some ideas:
- hands/handshake
- rings
- plugs/plugged
- heart/broken

Good luck! Curious what you have come up with in the end!

Answer (score -1):

I think the best and most-used icon nowadays is:

[image]

Comment: My immediate thought was "connecting to server", are you suggesting this also represents connections between people? I'm not looking for a network connection but a social or professional connection, a relationship of sorts.

Comment: my mistake. |o|